# Do's and dont's for rabies by dog bites

Tags: rabies

I play with stray dogs in India. None of them are vaccinated or anything. Yesterday a puppy was chewing my finger as usual but his teeth have grown and it caused a wound. I got my first injection today. So can I play with them during the rabies course? If they bite me again during the course or after it, will I need another vaccination? Please tell, thank you.